# Python Script to check website for a tag

Tags: python, html, linux, scripting, cron

I'm trying to figure out how to go about writing a website monitoring script (cron job in the end) to open up a given URL, check to see if a tag exists, and if the tag does not exist, or doesn't contain the expected data, then to write some to a log file, or to send an e-mail.

The tag would be something like  or something relatively similar.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet imo is to check out [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Something like so:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://yoursite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# See the docs on how to search through the soup. I'm not sure what
# you're looking for so my example stops here :)
```

After that, emailing it or logging it is pretty standard fare.

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample code (untested) that log and send mail:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import urllib2
import smtplib

#Log config
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/yourscript.log',level=logging.INFO,)

#Open requested url
url = "http://yoursite.com/tags/yourTag"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)

if check_content(data):
   #Report to log
   logging.info('Content found')
else:
   #Send mail
   send_mail('Content not found')

def check_content(data):
    #Your BeautifulSoup logic here
    return content_found

def send_mail(message_body):
    server = 'localhost'
    recipients = ['you@yourdomain.com']
    sender = 'script@yourdomain.com'
    message = 'From: %s \n Subject: script result \n\n %s' % (sender, message_body)
    session = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    session.sendmail(sender,recipients,message);
```

I would code `check_content()` function using [beautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Answer (score 1):

The following (untested) code uses urllib2 to grab the page and re to search it.

```
import urllib2,StringIO

pageString = urllib2.urlopen('**insert url here**').read()
m = re.search(r'**insert regex for the tag you want to find here**',pageString)
if m == None:
    #take action for NOT found here
else:
    #take action for found here
```

The following (untested) code uses pycurl and StringIO to grab the page and re to search it.

```
import pycurl,re,StringIO

b = StringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, '**insert url here**')
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.perform()
c.close()
m = re.search(r'**insert regex for the tag you want to find here**',b.getvalue())
if m == None:
    #take action for NOT found here
else:
    #take action for found here
```